# Enable handler with a core-expression when text is selected in editor

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I have a handler that should only be enabled when some text is selected in the current active editor.

I tried to implement this logic with a core-expression:

```xml
   <enabledWhen>
      <with
            variable="selection">
         <iterate
               operator="or">
            <and>
               <instanceof
                     value="org.eclipse.jface.text.ITextSelection">
               </instanceof>
               <not>
                  <test
                        property="length"
                        value="0">
                  </test>
               </not>
            </and>
         </iterate>
      </with>
   </enabledWhen>
```

It doesn't work and I'm not able to find out why. Can someone tell me how to write the core-expression correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't see any property testers defined for `org.eclipse.jface.text.ITextSelection` anywhere so the `test` will fail.

I think you would have to write your own property tester using the `org.eclipse.core.expressions.propertyTesters` extension point to add the length test.

Answer (score 1):

I got it to work with my own propertyTester.

`pom.xml`, the definition of the property tester:

```
  <extension point="org.eclipse.core.expressions.propertyTesters">
     <propertyTester
           class="x.TextSelectionTester"
           id="x.TextSelectionTester"
           namespace="x"
           properties="nonEmpty"
           type="org.eclipse.jface.text.ITextSelection">
     </propertyTester>
  </extension>
```

`pom.xml`, this time the usage of the property tester:

```
   <enabledWhen>
      <with
            variable="selection">
         <test
               property="x.nonEmpty"
               value="true">
         </test>
      </with>
   </enabledWhen>
```

The Java code:

```
import org.eclipse.core.expressions.PropertyTester;
import org.eclipse.jface.text.ITextSelection;

class TextSelectionTester extends PropertyTester {

  private static final String NonEmptyProperty = "nonEmpty";

  public boolean nonEmpty(ITextSelection selection) {
    return selection.getLength() != 0;
  }

  public boolean test(Object receiver, String property, Object[] args, Object expectedValue) {
    if (receiver instanceof ITextSelection && NonEmptyProperty.equals(property))
        return nonEmpty((ITextSelection) receiver);
    return false;
  }
}
```